# How to add global styles in sapper

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sapper

Currenly I'm using [this](https://github.com/deanpress/sapper-tailwind-webpack-starter) template, and I want to change my global font-family to "Poppins". How can I do that?

Heres my attempts but it still doesn't work.

```
static/tailwind.css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<style>
  :global(a) {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
</style>
```

or

```html
<style lang="scss">
  :global {
    @import 'stylesheets/main.scss';
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah solved, just add this on my `src/index.svelte`, but I still wonder about other alternative solution.

```
<style global>
  * {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
  }
</style>
```